# How do I make RGeo::Feature::Geometry methods available to RGeo::Geographic::SphericalMultiPolygonImpl?

Tags: postgis, rgeo

I am using Rails 4.2 with PostGIS, rgeo and the activerecord-postgis-adapter gem on Ubuntu. I have also installed the following libraries: libgeos++-dev libgeos-3.4.2 libgeos-c1 libgeos-dbg libgeos-dev libgeos-doc libgeos-ruby1.8 ruby-geos. An RGeo::Error::UnsupportedOperation is being raised when I call contains? on an RGeo::Geographic::SphericalMultiPolygonImpl. How do I make the Feature::Geometry methods available to my RGeo::Geographic::SphericalMultiPolygonImpl?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to break up that multipolygon into pieces and run a "contains" call on each of them. I'm guessing the #contains method must be run on one polygon at a time. Here's what that operation might look like:

```
responses = {}
n = this_shape.num_geometries
(0..n).to_a.each do |i|
  responses[i] = this_shape.geometry_n(i).contains?(other_shape)
end
```

Alternatively, you could break up those multipolygons into individual polygons and then run the loop on the array...